# How do i centre align a text from a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my basic code but I don't know what to add after the def

```
def centre(s, width=70):
    lines = open ('poem.txt ', 'r'). readlines ()
    stripped = []
    for line in lines:
        stripped.append(line.strip())
```

Comment: Do you want text center aligned within a larger string? In the console? to a file? to a string?

Comment: I have a file with the text(poem.txt) and I want to be centre aligned after I run the program(I am new to python. So sorry for my lack of language)

Comment: You want to reformat `poem.txt`, you mean? Also it always helps to show examples - those transcend language barriers ;)

Comment: How do you define your center?

Comment: I want a program that can show me after I run it the poem.txt centre aligned

Answer (score 4):

You may want to look into the `str.format()` function. If you read [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec) you'll find that it has the ability to center text:

```
>>> "{0:^40}".format(" Ministry of Silly Walks ")
'        Ministry of Silly Walks         '
>>> "{0:=^40}".format(" Ministry of Silly Walks ")
'======= Ministry of Silly Walks ========'
```

Comment: Sorry for my lack of understanding basic programming. But how do I open  the file using your program?

Comment: You already had a way to do that in your original question: `lines = open ('poem.txt ', 'r'). readlines ()`. Just adapt it accordingly.

Comment: It tells that the name 'lines' is not defined

Answer (score 3):

python provides a `str.center(width[,fillchar])` method.

```
for line in lines:
   print(line.center(width))
```

or similar

http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#string-methods