# Loading .data file into Python and Centering it

Tags: python

I am trying to load a .data file into my python code.
Once it has been loaded I need to center it using the center() function.
How do you do this?

```
file_object = open("cloud.data",'r')
print (file_object)

new_file_object = file_object.center(5)
print (new_file_object)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i centre align a text from a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19390158/how-do-i-centre-align-a-text-from-a-file)

Comment: What exactly is a .data file?