# How do I center text that I write into a text file in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have searched for an answer, but I am not sure if this is even possible.
I have written a function which creates a header for a text file:

```
def file_Header():
    ''' Create the text file header '''
    sentence = ("Test text for the upcoming project")
    sentence2 = ("This machine is curretnly online")
    width = 35

    with open('test.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write('##' + '#' * width + '##\n')
        file.write('#' + ' ' * (width+1) + ' #\n')

        for line in wrap(sentence, width):
            file.write('# {0:^{1}} #\n'.format(line, width))

        for line in wrap(sentence2, width):
            file.write('# {0:^{1}} #\n'.format(line, width))

        file.write('#' + ' ' * (width+1) + ' #\n')
        file.write('##' + '#'*(width) + '##\n')
```

This text formatting solution was found on another stackoverflow page and it functions very well.  However, I would know if I could center the output in the text file?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: it depends on what you mean by "center". Do you mean centered in term of width? or literally in the "center" of the file? etc. Here one way if you meant width: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19390288/12349101

Comment: Center of text file line does NOT exist. But, if you know what will be the size of the file when it's opened you could try to change the witdh value. Your centered text in 80 rows will never be centered in my 100 rows editor. It could be done if you say "center in console", because console can know how much rows has been placed. Text files do nothing, just holds characters.

Comment: Ah, ok.  I meant centering in terms of width.

Comment: "center of file" can exist though? especially if they define what they mean by that in this context. eg: if you use a file of a certain size, you can calculate the center of it in term of lines, bytes, etc, and then place whatever text you want there. so it "depends".  @m3nda

Answer (score 1):

Technically a textfile has no middle because there is no default max line length.  It will store as many characters as you want without ever inserting a line break on your behalf.  However if you were to make some arbitrary number to represent the maximum line length then this is absolutely possible.  All you would need to do is take the longest line of your output, subtract that from the maximum line length and cut that number in half, and you get the amount of padding you would need to insert before each of your output lines.

For example:

```
from textwrap import wrap

def file_Header(max_len = 80):
    ''' Create the text file header '''
    sentence = ("Test text for the upcoming project")
    sentence2 = ("This machine is curretnly online")
    width = 35
    padding = " " * (max_len - (width + 4))//2
    with open('test.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write(padding + '##' + '#' * width + '##\n')
        file.write(padding + '#' + ' ' * (width+1) + ' #\n')

        for line in wrap(sentence, width):
            file.write(padding + '# {0:^{1}} #\n'.format(line, width))

        for line in wrap(sentence2, width):
            file.write(padding + ('# {0:^{1}} #\n'.format(line, width)))

        file.write(padding + '#' + ' ' * (width+1) + ' #\n')
        file.write(padding + '##' + '#'*(width) + '##\n')
```

Output:

```
                     ######################################
                     ##                                  ##
                     ##                                  ##
                     ##Test text for the upcoming project##
                     ## This machine is curretnly online ##
                     ##                                  ##
                     ##                                  ##
                     ######################################
```

Comment: While this is ok, if you use a 1000 char lengh for lines, then your center doesn't represent the screen. I bet that the file will be displayed into a screen. If you use a low char count for lenght, then texty may appear centered, but to be exact, NO center of line exists if there's no value to play with. In your example, your witdh could be broken by a single line that exceeed the expected result.

Comment: @m3nda  Yes... that Is precisely why I used the word arbitrary when I said you can choose a maximum line length.

Comment: Agree, I voted you because it's an quite good alternative, but it's important to made OP understand that the concept "center" is not available as is in terms of text lines.